# Is it appropriate to compare SVM coefficients with random forest feature importances?

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn to build two binary classification models--one is a random forest, and the other is a linear SVM. I want to compare the relative importances of the input features to the trained models.

LinearSVC has an attribute "coef_" while the random forest classifier has an attribute "feature_importances_". I know that they are not computed on the same scale but, from what I've read, both represent the learned importances of the features.

If I transform the coefficients and feature importances to the same scale, would it be appropriate to compare the relative importances/weights assigned to each feature to understand how the two models differ in learning the data?

Comment: No, because random forest importance metrics are based on out-of-bag observations and there is no such thing in the development of SVM.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit of an opinion-based question, so FWIW here's my opinion.

I think it's fine to compare them qualitatively ('feature A is more important than feature B', 'the models agree that feature C is noise', etc).

And I think rescaling them for a quantitative comparison is an interesting idea, but I am not aware of any theory supporting it or suggesting how to do it. Perhaps softmax scaling could work? I think it's a research topic.

By the way, you might want to check out [`sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html) too.